# How can I find out if the MainActivity is being paused from my Java class?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-lifecycle

I am using motion sensor detection in my application.

My design is this: **a class gets the sensor services references from the main activity** and then it implements SensorEventListener. That is, the MainActivity does not listen for sensor event changes:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... code
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    // The following is my java class, it does not extends any android fragment/activty
    mShakeUtil = new ShakeUtil(mSensorManager,mAccelerometer,this);
    // ..more code..
}
```

I **can't redesign** ShakeUtil so it is a fragment nor activity, unfortunately.  Now to illustrate the problem consider:

- MainActivity is on its way to be destroyed/paused. I.e screen rotation
- ShakeUtil's onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) gets called in the process..

One of the things that happen inside onSensorChanged is a dialog interaction, which gives the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

When the previous happens between MainActivity's onSaveInstanceState and onPause. I know this can be prevented if I successfully detect that MainActivity is being pause in ShakeUtil.

**How can I detect that MainActivity is being paused or onSaveInstanceState was called from ShakeUtil?**

Alternatively, how can I avoid this issue without making Shakeutil extend activity?

So far I have tried with flag variables but that isn't good enough, I guess these are not atomic operations. I tried using Activity's isChangingConfigurations(), but I get an undocummented "NoSuchMethodFound" error.. I am unregistering the sensors by calling ShakeUtil when onPause in main ACtivity